# Chrome case sensitive Ctrl-F

Tags: google-chrome, browser, find

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Case sensitive searches in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/192437/case-sensitive-searches-in-google-chrome)

is there anyway we can do a case sensitive search when we do Ctrl-F in google chrome?

Answer (score 11):

This is not possible in Google Chrome. There is a [discussion](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8717#c32) about this issue and Google's Chrome project member Jeff C. says:

> Discussed w/ UI leads: This would be
>   nice to have, but we're not willing to
>   add the options to the UI at this
>   time.
>   Apr 6, 2011

Note: Firefox and IE supports case-sensitive search.