# How do I perform a case-sensitive search in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Case sensitive searches in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/192437/case-sensitive-searches-in-google-chrome)

Hitting `Ctrl-F` brings up the search box but a "case sensitive" option is nowhere to be found. Does the feature exist at all in Chrome?

Comment: Doesn't exist yet, nope.

Comment: I noticed this was posted 7yr ago. Does anyone know if this is possible yet?

Comment: I think their priority is to keep feature of signing you into the google in the browser so it can track you over the whole internet. See also https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=687552

Comment: Partial solution is https://www.labnol.org/internet/case-sensitive-find/28186/ The code can be copy pasted instead of webaddress into the bookmark so its called bookmarklet.

Comment: Firefox has it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8717 - not currently

Comment: I just lost 8 hours of productivity because this feature is missing. I had a typo (uppercase vs lowercase) in my aws lambda ARN and it super difficult to find out why IAM permissions weren't working!