# Disable emoji icons in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, regex, google-chrome-extensions, emoticons

I want to disable emoji in Chrome, or replace them with something else (not for any particularly deep reason - figured it'd be amusing).

I'm using an extension called [Word Replacer II](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/word-replacer-ii/djakfbefalbkkdgnhkkdiihelkjdpbfh?hl=en), which allows me to replace text on a web page based on a Regex search.

How can I select all emoji on the page using Regex?

Answer (score 0):

Use the emoji matcher for a library such as [lodash](https://thekevinscott.com/emojis-in-javascript/):

```
(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?(?:\u200d(?:[^\ud800-\udfff]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?)*
```

Package it as part of a [userscript or bookmarklet](https://superuser.com/questions/192437/) to implement the find/replace behavior. Run a node.js server withe the [emoji-regex](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex) module to automate this completely.

**References**

- [Emojis in Javascript](https://thekevinscott.com/emojis-in-javascript/)
- [GitHub - mathiasbynens/emoji-regex: A regular expression to match all Emoji-only symbols as per the Unicode Standard.](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex)