# How to do a whole word search in Chrome's Find dialog

Tags: google-chrome

In using Chrome's Find (Ctrl+F) search functionality on a rendered page how do I constrain the search to things like case sensitive or whole word?

[image: Chrome's search mode]

Comment: Possible duplicate (case sensitive search): https://superuser.com/questions/192437/case-sensitive-searches-in-google-chrome. To find whole words only there is a workaround by enclosing the keyword with spaces.

Comment: Use Firefox when needed

Answer (score 14):

I found an extension called [FindR](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/findr/bidnaaogcagbdidehabnjfedabckhdgc/) that will do the trick. The extension (no affiliation) is meant to find AND replace, but it works perfectly as a Find-only tool as well. There are separate checkboxes to Match Case, and match Whole Words Only.

If you wanted to get fancier, you could use a RegEx extension such as [Chrome Regex Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-regex-search/bpelaihoicobbkgmhcbikncnpacdbknn). That one even allows you to remap the Ctrl-F hotkey.

Comment: RegEx extension Chrome Regex Search is excellent.  +1. Thanks for the tip @Paul